# ST3 - Build System Supporting packages in java

Tags: java, windows, cmd, sublimetext3, build-system

This is my case:
I have a Project Folder in Documents named "JavaProgs2"
It has many .java files, 1 Directory for classpaths called "Classes" & 2 Packages (Directories) "myPack1" and "myPack2" which has files "Parent.java" and "Child.java" respectively.
"Child.java" imports a method from "Parent.java"
My java Build System in ST3 is :

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac","-d","$folder/Classes", "$file"],
    "working_dir":"$folder",
    "path": "D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin",
    "shell": true,
    "variants": [

        {   
            "cmd": ["start","cmd", "/k", "java", "$file_base_name"],
            "working_dir":"$folder/Classes",
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have no problems in compiling any .java file be it in a package or in the Project Folder.
But, when running the files I get the "could not find or load..." error.
So is there any replacement for
`"java", "$file_base_name"`
which will send a command like 
`java <package name>.<classname>`
 when required to CMD from the working_dir ??
Maybe there's something like `$folder_name.$file_base_name` which i can use in the build system

I prefer not to use an IDE.

---

EDIT:

I want to edit the RUN variant of my build system for that I need this help:
Is there a way to Strip a Path like 

`D:\Users\Horcrux\Documents\JavaProgs2\Classes\myPack1\Parent.class`
 to just
 
`myPack1/Parent`

or similarly

`D:\Users\Horcrux\Documents\JavaProgs2\Classes\myPack1\blahblah\abc\Test.class`
 to just
 
`myPack1/blahblah/abc/Test` ???

IN short only the path After the "worikng_dir" till the $file_base_name is sent to CMD from Sublime Text with replacing "\" to "/", where the working_dir is

```
"D:\Users\Horcrux\Documents\JavaProgs2\Classes\"
```

---

EDIT 2:
Okay I figured out this much.. it's very close.In the build system I entered this snippet:

```
${file/(D.+?s2\\\\)||(.java)//g}
```

Which sends this command to CMD:

```
java myPack1\test3\_2ArithmeticOperations
```

Now only thing i cant figure out is how to replace "\" to "/"
Can you please try to edit the snippet to perform the replacement also?

Comment: Please help anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather unclear, but you can find all of the available [build system variables](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#variables) in the official docs. You may also be interested in learning about [substitutions](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions) using regular expressions - the link is to the snippets page, but substitutions work the same way in build systems.

Comment: Sorry the guide is going above my head. I have edited the post. I hope it is a bit more clear. Thanks a lot for the help though :)